# mongo bson insert/read child records

Tags: c#, mongodb, bson, database

I would like to insert a record with children, and then display the written contents on the screen in c#. This is what I have so far:

```
    MongoCollection<BsonDocument> house= building.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("house");
    BsonDocument rooms= new BsonDocument {
                { "roomName", name},
                { "location",  <--child array here: 1stfloor, 2ndlfloor, topfloor.
                { "roomID", guidstring}
                };

    house.Insert(rooms);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you  mean for debugging purposes? You can convert the document to a JSON string for that:

```
Console.WriteLine(rooms.ToJson());
```

You can also use the mongo shell to look at your documents. Run the mongo shell and then type:

```
> use buildings // or whatever your database name is
> db.house.find()
... your documents displayed here
>
```

If your collection has lots of documents you will probably want to include some kind of query to narrow down which documents are displayed.

You should also consider defining a domain model using C# classes and letting the driver convert them to and from BSON documents for you.